# Check whether key value pair exists in every object of array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, object

I have following json data :

```
{
  records:{
          data:{
              current:{
                     records:{
                        '2years':[{a:1, b:2, flag:true},
                                  {a:2, b:4},
                                  {a:3, b:5, flag:true},
                                  {a:4, b:2}]
                     }
              }
          }
  }
}
```

I have two objects as `flag_true={}` and `flag_false={}`

I want to iterate over '2years' array and check whether `flag:true` exists or not in every object.

If it exists I want to push the object from 2years array into flag_true object else it will go in flag_false.

The final result should be

```
{
flag_true:[{a:1, b:2, flag:true},
           {a:3, b:5, flag:true}]
flag_false:[{a:2, b:4},
            {a:4, b:2} ]
}
```

Note that

The key 'current' is dynamic and can be either of 'current' or 'previous'

Same with array name..It can be '3years', '4years' as well

How can I do this in javascript?

please help. thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried a normal loop and an `if` statement?

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? There are already multiple questions on how to work with objects that have dynamic property names.

Comment: I have tried Objects.keys() but I am not getting the result

Answer (score 1):

```js
function convertRecord(array) {
    return array.reduce((obj, el) => {
        obj[el.flag ? 'flag_true' : 'flag_false'].push(el);
        return obj;
    }, {
        flag_true: [],
        flag_false: []
    })
}

const data = {
  records:{
          data:{
              current:{
                     records:{
                        '2years':[{a:1, b:2, flag:true},
                                  {a:2, b:4},
                                  {a:3, b:5, flag:true},
                                  {a:4, b:2}],
                                  
                        '3years':[{a:1, b:2, flag:true},
                                  {a:2, b:4},
                                  {a:3, b:5, flag:true},
                                  {a:4, b:2}]
                     }
              }
          }
  }
}

for(const key in data.records.data.current.records) {
  data.records.data.current.records[key] = convertRecord(data.records.data.current.records[key]);
}

console.log(data);
```

Comment: How can iterate over the object to access the array

Comment: @RoDev I added an example of iterating using for in to the answer

Comment: @ Darth: The key 'current' is dynamic..It can be 'previous' as well...Also there will be only one array not multiple arrays

Comment: @RoDev So use for..in for `data.records.data`

Comment: can you please elaborate...I did not get